# Error message when installing Ubuntu on PC but not on laptop

Tags: system-installation

I have a problem when trying to install Ubuntu 17.04, 64 bit on PC. I have a bootable pendrive which is booting and running on the laptop but not on PC.

This is the error message I get on PC:

[image]

Comment: Hint: what video cards do you have on the two different systems?

Comment: PC - MSI GeForce GTX 970 Gaming, laptop Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I must choose "nomodeset" in settings. Sorry for problem.